# MongoDB Drivers - Wrap the mongodb nodejs drivers to add extra functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb

As the title says, I want to add extra methods to the mongodb drivers.
Currently i'm using a collection instance to to insert, delete documents in my database like this:

```js
// dbConn.js
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
export default const db = client.db("dbName");
```

```js
//colName.js
import db form "dbConn.js"

const collection = db.collection("colName")

const data = [ ]
collection.insertMany(data)
```

But I would like to add some methods to the collection instance, to do something like this:

```js
collection.modifiedInsertMany(data)
```

I guess, I could create my own class:

```js
class myCollection {
  col = db.collection("collName");
  
  function modifiedInsertMany(data) {
    // do stuff with data
    return col.insertMany(data);
  }
}
```

But if i did that I would have to rewrite every single method of the original mongodb.Collection, isn't that correct?
If possible, I want to keep all the methods of the mongodb.Collection and just add a couple of  my methods.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You can try extending the Mongo Collection, `class MyCollection extends Mongo.Collection`

Comment: Is using mongoose an option for you? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics

Comment: @JacobStephenson this is written in the mongodb docs: "The Collection class is an internal class that embodies a MongoDB collection allowing for insert/update/remove/find and other command operation on that MongoDB collection.

COLLECTION Cannot directly be instantiated", [link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.4/classes/Collection.html). I thought doing that but how to I call super() in my class constructor?

Comment: @Mina I guess in the end I could use mongoose, but I would prefer not to. Finding a solution while using the mongodb drivers would be the best for me.

Comment: Are you really going to create a separate `new MongoClient` in every collection module that you write?

Comment: @Bergi No, not really. I didn't express that clearly in my  example. I  create a single client for the app and export a db instance. Then, I create collection instances for each collection in the db. I'll edit the question also.

Comment: In that case, just `export function modifiedInsertMany(data) { …; return col.insertMany(…); }` from *colName.js*, or even do `collection.modifiedInsertMany = function(data) { …; return this.insertMany(…); };`

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your help, but it seems your solution won't work if I use typescript. I guess, I will have to use the mongodb collection as a class field and then shadow the methods I will need.

Comment: The first pattern should just work. The second might require some type assertions, start with an `interface MySpecialCollection extends mongo.Collection { … }` and then do something like `const collection: MySpecialCollection = Obect.assign(db.collection("colName"), {modifiedInsertMany(data) { … }});`